# d-ary heap and percolateUp() problems

Tags: java, heap

I'm a student learning java heaps atm, and we have an assignment wher we have to take a class the teachers made and change it so that it works as a d-heap, and then test it with another teacher class. I've gotten most things to work, but one of the JUnit tests we're supposed to run always fails in a certain place: testValues(5, 23, 17, 12); (expected 23, but was 12).
I quite sure the issue is somewhere in Insert() or percolateUp(), but I'm out of ideas.

```
package alda.heap;
import java.util.Arrays;            
import java.util.Comparator;            

public class DHeap<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>
{
private int d;  //added
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
private int currentSize = 0;      // Number of elements in heap
private AnyType [ ] array; // The heap array
protected Comparator comparator;

public DHeap( )
{

    this( DEFAULT_CAPACITY, DEFAULT_CAPACITY ); //added Default_capacity
}


public DHeap( int capacity, int d ) 
{

    this.d=d;       //added
    array = (AnyType[]) new Comparable[ capacity + 1 ];
}



public DHeap(int d) {       //added
    if (d < 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("d bigger than 1 plz");
    }
        this.d=d;
        array = (AnyType[]) new Comparable[ DEFAULT_CAPACITY + 1 ];
}


public int size(){ 
    return currentSize; 
    }

public AnyType get(int index){ 
    return array[index]; 
    }

public void insert( AnyType x )  //teacher made, gets error from JUnit.
{
    if(x == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("cannot insert null");
    }
    if(array.length -1 == currentSize){
        enlargeArray();
    }
        // Percolate up
    int hole = ++currentSize;
    for( array[ 0 ] = x; x.compareTo( array[ hole / 2 ] ) < 0; hole /= 2 )
        array[ hole ] = array[ hole / 2 ];
    array[ hole ] = x;
    //percolateUp(currentSize - 1); //my method, which doesnt work
}

private void percolateUp(int childIndex){ //made by me

    AnyType tmp = array[childIndex];

    while(childIndex > 0)
    {
        if(tmp.compareTo(array[getParentIndex(childIndex)]) < 0){
        array[childIndex] = array[getParentIndex(childIndex)];
        childIndex = getParentIndex(childIndex);
    }
    array[childIndex] = tmp;
}
}


public boolean isFull(){        //added method
    return currentSize == array.length -1;
}

private void enlargeArray(){    //made from scratch
    System.out.println("1");
    array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length * 2);
    System.out.println("2");
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void enlargeArray1( ){   
    AnyType [] old = array;
        array = (AnyType []) new Comparable[old.length * 2];
        for( int i = 0; i < old.length; i++ )
            array[ i ] = old[ i ];        
}


public AnyType findMin( )
{
    if( isEmpty( ) )
        throw new UnderflowException();
    return array[ 1 ];
}

public AnyType deleteMin( )
{
    if( isEmpty( ) )
        throw new UnderflowException( );

    AnyType minItem = findMin( );
    array[ 1 ] = array[ currentSize-- ];
    percolateDown( 1 );

    return minItem;
}

public boolean isEmpty( )
{
    return currentSize == 0;
}

private int getParentIndex(int index) {
    return (index - 1) / d;
    }

public int getChildIndex(int index, int k){
    return d * index + k;
}

public void makeEmpty( )
{
    currentSize = 0;
}

private void percolateDown( int hole )
{
    int child;
    AnyType tmp = array[ hole ];

    for( ; hole * 2 <= currentSize; hole = child )
    {
        child = hole * 2;
        if( child != currentSize &&
                array[ child + 1 ].compareTo( array[ child ] ) < 0 )
            child++;
        if( array[ child ].compareTo( tmp ) < 0 )
            array[ hole ] = array[ child ];
        else
            break;
    }
    array[ hole ] = tmp;
}



    // Test program
public static void main( String [ ] args )
{
    int numItems = 10000;
    DHeap<Integer> h = new DHeap<>( );
    int i = 37;

    for( i = 37; i != 0; i = ( i + 37 ) % numItems )
        h.insert( i );
    for( i = 1; i < numItems; i++ )
        if( h.deleteMin( ) != i )
            System.out.println( "Oops! " + i );
}
```

My test Class:

```
package org.junit;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Random;
import org.junit.Before;
import alda.heap.DHeap;
public class DHeapTester {

private DHeap<Integer> heap = new DHeap<Integer>(4);

@Test
public void testFunctionality() {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    PriorityQueue<Integer> oracle = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();

    assertEquals(oracle.isEmpty(), heap.isEmpty());

    for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++) {
        int tal = rnd.nextInt(1000);
        heap.insert(tal);
        oracle.add(tal);
        while (!heap.isEmpty() && rnd.nextBoolean()) {
            assertEquals(oracle.poll(), heap.deleteMin());
        }
        assertEquals(oracle.isEmpty(), heap.isEmpty());
    }
}

@Test
public void testConstructors() {
    heap = new DHeap<Integer>(); 
    heap = new DHeap<Integer>(2); 
    heap = new DHeap<Integer>(3);                                   
}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testTooSmallD() {
    new DHeap<Integer>(1);
}

private void testValues(Integer... expected) {
    assertEquals(expected.length, heap.size());
    for (int n = 0; n < expected.length; n++)
        assertEquals(expected[n], heap.get(n + 1));
}

@Test
public void testContent() {
    testValues();
    heap.insert(17);
    testValues(17);
    heap.insert(23);
    testValues(17, 23);
    heap.insert(5);
    testValues(5, 23, 17);
    heap.insert(12);
    testValues(5, 23, 17, 12);  //this is where JUnit gets error (expected 23 but was 12)
    heap.insert(100);
    heap.insert(51);
    heap.insert(52);
    testValues(5, 23, 17, 12, 100, 51, 52);
    heap.insert(4);
    testValues(4, 5, 17, 12, 100, 51, 52, 23);
    heap.insert(70);
    testValues(4, 5, 17, 12, 100, 51, 52, 23, 70);
    heap.insert(10);
    testValues(4, 5, 10, 12, 100, 51, 52, 23, 70, 17);
    heap.insert(1);
    testValues(1, 5, 4, 12, 100, 51, 52, 23, 70, 17, 10);

    assertEquals(1, (int) heap.deleteMin());
    testValues(4, 5, 10, 12, 100, 51, 52, 23, 70, 17);
    assertEquals(4, (int) heap.deleteMin());
    testValues(5, 17, 10, 12, 100, 51, 52, 23, 70);
    assertEquals(5, (int) heap.deleteMin());
    testValues(10, 17, 70, 12, 100, 51, 52, 23);
}
```

Comment: The debugger is your friend. Step through your code with the debugger, and check each insertion.

Answer (score 0):

In your insert, percolateUp and percolateDown methods, you need to use `getParent()` and `getChild()` methods. Currently, insert method divides indexes by 2 to get to the parent of an element which is **only true if you have a 2-heap.**

Also, your heap implementation uses `array[0]` as a placeholder. In that case, your `getParent()` and `getChild()` in their current implementations **do not work.** Current implementations of these functions work only if you start indexing from 0 which is not the case in this implementation.

For example, if you have a 2-heap with size 3, in your implementation, the indexes are (1, 2, 3). The parent of 2 is not `(2-1)/2`. Similarly, the children of 1 are not `2*1 + k` if k is being used as a positive index.

When you start indexing from 1, for a d-heap:
`parent of n: (n + (d-2))/d`
`children of n: ((n*d - (d-2)), ..., (n*d + 1))` where each element is an integer.

Comment: you explanation helped alot, and i feel stupid to ask this, but do you have a full version of the children of n Equation, my internet searches has not reached a consensus.

Comment: If you are OK with the parent equation, then finding the children can be summarized as follows: For a node `n`, `n` possibly has `d` children. Let the leftmost child has index `x`. Then the rightmost child has index `x + (d-1)`. The parent of x is `(x+(d-2))/d = n`. Thus, `x = n*d - (d-2)`. and the rightmost child `n*d - (d-2) + (d-1) = n*d + 1`. Thus we get the above tuple.